# How does magento 2 calculate price of configurable products?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I am a magento 2 starter with much experience in magento 1. I can't find the relevant scripts which are used to calculate the price for configurable products.

I need a basic guide on how the configuration works please so that I can modify it.

E.g. I need to add a customise-able option with title **Length** and the price should change based on it's value.

So if the price is $1000 and 1000 millimetres is set then the price should be $1000,

if 500 millimetres is set, then the price should be 500$.

If 2000 millimetres is set then the price should be 2000$ and so on...

```
price = (price * (length / 1000))
```

Where do I have to add this logic?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 config product price is different with Magento 1.

- In Magento 1 the price is calculated based on super attributes.
- In Magento 2 the price is taken from child product.

In your case, we have two methods:

1. Using Magento Backend: Generate the children with option **Apply unique prices by attribute to each SKU**, enter fixed price to each value of **length** attribute.
2. Using Magento source code: create a 3rd module and override `getValue()` function in `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/BasePrice.php` class using `di.xml`.
   The code should be:

   ```
   public function getValue()
   {
       if ($this->value === null) {
           $this->value = false;
           foreach ($this->priceInfo->getPrices() as $price) {
               if ($price instanceof BasePriceProviderInterface && $price->getValue() !== false) {
                   $this->value = min($price->getValue(), $this->value ?: $price->getValue());
               }
           }
       }
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($this->product->getId());
       if ($product) {
           $length = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('length')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
           if ($length) {
               $this->value = $this->value * ($length / 1000);
           }
       }
       return $this->value;
   }
   ```

   Tested in Magento 2.3.0

That's it.

Comment: But the length attribute ranges from 0 to 6000, so do I need to create 6000 values? I think it would be better to create a logic so that the price is multiplied by length / 1000.

Comment: @Black So it's configurable product + length or simple product + length. So you will need to override the Core function in order to change the price. Let create an override module for this.

Comment: And where are the relevant files? I also need to do this for the price display on the frontend, how does magento know which price to show in frontend? Does it work by javascript, is a request to a controller made?

Comment: @Black If you only want to change the base price (excluding tax and option prices), let override this file `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/BasePrice.php`. Add this line at the end of `getValue()` function (before return): `$this->value = $this->value * ($this->product->getLength / 1000))`

Comment: ok, but note that not every configurable product will have a length. Does it also take care of the calculation in the frontend?

Comment: So you will need to put the code above inside an `if statement`, `if ($this->product->getLength) { your code }`

Comment: I know, but is this the only place where I have to change the code? Or are there other scripts too which I have to take care of, so that the right price is displayed if I change the length on the product site?

Comment: @Black ConfiguredPrice extend from FinalPrice and FinalPrice get value from BasePrice, so BasePrice is the class you have to override. Let try overriding it to see the magic :)

Comment: hey thx for your effort, I will try it out as soon as possible :)

Comment: I tried your code. The configurator does not show any options if I use your code. The individual option with title "Length" does exist.

Comment: How did you do it? This code does not affect the options.Maybe it's an error occurred, turn on debug mode to figure out it.

Comment: I just used your code 1:1. My "length" is an configurable option though.

Comment: Sorry I think it's a mistake. This code `$this->product->getLength` should be `$this->product->getLength()`. When developing a magento store, you should turn on debug mode. That's why we need the IDEs.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I tried it with () now the options show but the price is not calculated in the frontend

Comment: Did you clear Magento cache, re-index and Ctrl + F5? Magento is quite complicated in cache and index management

Comment: It will work well because I've tried this code in my Magento 2 store :). Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95893/discussion-between-black-and-jamy).